# Oracle APEX: Show value of binding variable

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

Currently, I am a newbier of Apex. I create a page with 2 text box (YEAR and MONTH) and 1 button to submit value of 2 text box into PL/SQL script

```
DECLARE
count_files NUMBER;
BEGIN

select count(*) into count_files 
from FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT_VIEW
where FAC_MONTH = :P6_MONTH and FAC_YEAR = :P6_YEAR;

IF count_files = 0 THEN
    -- insert something
END IF;
END;
```

The issue is the PL/SQl code does not work and I don't know how to print the value of 2 binding text box (:P6_MONTH and :P6_YEAR) to debug

Comment: Please explain what  "does not work" means in this scenario

Comment: If you want to know the values of your items in Apex for debugging purposes, you can use javascript. Put this script on the "execute when page loads" part of your page: `alert($v('P6_MONTH') + ' ' + $v('P6_YEAR'));`

Comment: @Rene: 'Does not work' mean the value of :P6_MONTH and :P6_YEAR is null. So I want to print out to check their values. This is a case of debug

Comment: @Vance: Thanks for your answer. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
htp.p('<script language="javascript">');
htp.p('alert("'||:P6_MONTH||'");');
htp.p('</script>');
```